# Google.Apis.Fitness.v1 .NET library: Insufficient Permission [403] error

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use the Google.Apis.Fitness.v1 .NET library as follows, and getting a permission error on the last line of the sample (aggregate request execution). I have enabled Fitness API for my project.

How can I solve the error?

```
string clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";//From Google Developer console 
string clientSecret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";//From Google Developer console 
string userName = Environment.UserName; 
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityWrite,
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityRead,
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessBodyWrite,
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessBodyRead,
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessLocationRead,
    FitnessService.Scope.FitnessLocationWrite
};

UserCredential _userCred = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret
    },
    scopes,
    "MY_USER",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Google.Fitness.Auth", false)).Result;


FitnessService _fitnessService = new FitnessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = _userCred,
        ApplicationName = "Fitness API Use",
    });


//Aggregate request
DateTime dt1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
AggregateRequest agR = new AggregateRequest();
agR.AggregateBy  = new List<AggregateBy>();
AggregateBy oneAgrBy = new AggregateBy();
oneAgrBy.DataSourceId = "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps";
oneAgrBy.DataTypeName =   "com.google.step_count.delta";
agR.AggregateBy.Add(oneAgrBy);
agR.BucketByActivityType  = new BucketByActivity();
agR.BucketByActivityType.MinDurationMillis = 5;
agR.StartTimeMillis = (long)(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5) - dt1970).TotalMilliseconds;
agR.EndTimeMillis = (long) (DateTime.Now - dt1970).TotalMilliseconds;

UsersResource.DatasetResource.AggregateRequest agRequest =  _fitnessService.Users.Dataset.Aggregate(agR, "me");
AggregateResponse agResponse = agRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because the site doesn't entertain questions for recommendation lists. Take a look at the tour and the help center to get a better understanding of how this site works, expecially the on-topic section.

Comment: I have changed the question with actual code-sample. Please help.

Comment: Is this C#? Please [edit] the question and add the tag for the language that you are using. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't enable the API in the Google Developers Console. Try following this link, with your project name:
https://console.cloud.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE/apiui/apiview/fitness/overview

Answer (score 0):

OK ..it turned out to be a problem with cached auth-response on local machine. Looks like under this app, I went through the authentication-authorization flow some time and things got stored in "Google.Fitness.Auth" folder. Mostly at that time as I was just trying with the things, the scope-list was not proper.

Later I changed the scope list the way I wanted. But it did not re-invoke authentication procedure. And things kept on giving error with old cached auth-response.

Now I just deleted "Google.Fitness.Auth" folder, and then above mentioned example worked fine.

So here the answer is: Delete the store-folder and try again.

But can somebody explain what should happen if the APP changes its scope-list? I expect the auth-process to trigger once again. But looks like, it does not happen.

Comment: We do delete the token in case we didn't manage to parse the response: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Flows/AuthorizationCodeFlow.cs#L314, which should work for you, since we won't be able to refresh the token. We might consider delete it also at https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/UserCredential.cs#L120 but I'm still not convinced. Feel free to open a new issue in our issue tracker or suggest a code fix. Thanks!